# Why am I getting a 404 response from my POST in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following action in my Web api controller:

```
 // POST api/<controller>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(string user, string password)
    {
         return true; 
    }
```

I am getting the following error with a 404 status when hitting it with either fiddler or a test jQuery script:

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/amsi-v8.0.0/api/account'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Account' that matches the request."}

My http route is as follows:

```
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Gets work fine. I found another question here which talks about removing WebDAV from IIS. I tried that, still same issue.

Why do I get a 404?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The default action selection behavior in ASP.NET Web API cares about your action method parameters as well. If they are simple type objects and they are not optional, you will need to supply them in order to invoke that particular action method. In your case, you should send a request against a URI as below:

> /api/account?user=Foo&password=bar

If you wanna get these values inside the request body rather than the query string (which is a better idea), just create a User object and send the request accordingly:

```
public class User { 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

Request:

> POST http://localhost:8181/api/account HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Host: localhost:8181
>
> Content-Length: 33
>
> {"Name": "foo", "Password":"bar"}

And your action method should look like something below:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(User user) {

    //do what u need to do here

    //return back the proper response.
    //e.g: If you have created something, return back 201

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, to not need to pass the values on the query string and pass them as POST values what would the signature of the Post action look like?

Comment: @PilotBob it is in the above answer.

Comment: I see the model, and the request, but not the post action in the controller. Would it just be public void Post(User user)??

Comment: Thanks... got it working. Much appreciated. It didn't make sense to me that if I used simple types in the parameters you had to put them on the query string. But a complex type it does model binding.

Comment: @PilotBob these are default conventions. Every one of them is extensible and you can stick your own logic if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

When we are posting a json it expect a class so create class in model folder like this

```
public class Credential
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get;set; }
}
```

and now change the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Post(Credential credential)
{
     return true; 
}
```

Try now everything will work smooth